# Can moderators surpass the daily limit of 20 reviews?

Tags: discussion, review, moderators, rate-limiting

I'm just curious about this. Can a moderator surpass the daily limit of 20 reviews?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the question is "Why?" since you've just confirmed we can.

Comment: In general, if the question is "can a moderator do ____," the answer is "yes." (Generally speaking.)

Comment: @anorton: Can a moderator do my laundry for me? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila [Mods can also come into your house at night and leave your milk out.](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/127139#127139)

Comment: @Fundamental: I don't have any milk, so they will have to bring their own...

Comment: @AsafKaragila They *can*, but the question is: *will they?* `:-)`

Comment: Wealll, it's a (hopefully benign) dictatorship, albeit an elected one.  I guess.  If they can do *anything*.

Comment: @anorton: I hope that they will step up to the challenge and will.

Comment: Moderators can do anything, yuppers.  Hopefully they do their *anything* ***moderately***.  One might even commend the saying, "***Moderation*** in all things . . ."

Comment: @Robert: But now by induction moderators have to moderate the times they moderate their moderation; but also to moderate the times they moderate the times they moderate their moderation; and so on ad infinitum. This sequence does not converge, and after $\omega$ steps there is still limit!

Comment: @AsafKaragila:   Recursive moderation!  I like that!  Something to keep the authorities occupied and looking the other way!  Cheers!

Answer (score 16):

> Moderators don't have a limit for the number of questions they can close, nor a limit for the number of the questions they can review in the close review queue.

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183757/259867), where you can also see the screenshot of a moderator with 60 close reviews in a day (vs the limit of 40 on Stack Overflow).

Comment: [No review limit for ♦ mods](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/259867), in any queue.