# Breaking daily limit of reviews

Tags: discussion, review

[image]

Today when I was checking review statistics, this showed up. I wonder how it is possible that a user breaks the daily limit of 20 reviews? Is it some kind of new privilege?

Comment: Maybe this might help: [Can moderators surpass the daily limit of 20 reviews?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19226) and [More than 20 reviews in a day](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21175).

Comment: Checking that the user in your screenshot reviewed [suggested edit on their own post](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/971450), it seems that the explanation given in the answer to the latter question applies also here.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you for the links. I guess this post will be marked duplicate soon…

Comment: @MartinSleziak Indeed, that's what happened.

Comment: @AlexFrancisco Oops! I did it again! :-)